# Assign a predefined GCP IAM role to a principal except one permission

Tags: security, google-cloud-platform, google-iam, identity-management

I want to grant the `container.developer` role to one IAM principal in GCP.

However I want **all** the permissions except 1 (`container.secrets.get`).

Is there an elegant way of going about this other than creating a custom role with all of those permissions (there are too many) except the above?